# jQuery enter behaves like tab, doesn't work with validators

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I need to navigate to a next control after pressing enter, like a tab. I have a such code:

```
('input').live("keypress", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var tabindex = $(this).attr('tabindex');
        ++tabindex;
        $('[tabindex=' + tabindex + ']').focus().select();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

It works perfect! But... If input has a validator, it doesn't work. After pressing enter the focus is the same and validator shows that the field is required. But I want to navigate to the next control. Can I bypass it? Any ideas? Thanks.

P.S. Pressing enter has to focus the next field ignoring all validators. Enter must only focus next control, not activate validators.

Comment: Whats the actual prob is ?? do you need to focus that field which is failed to validate or next field ??

Comment: I need to focus next field after pressing enter button even when the previous field has the validator.

Comment: try this if needed:  **setTimeout('$('[tabindex=' + tabindex + ']').focus().select()',1000);**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').live("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var tabindex = $(this).attr('tabindex');
        ++tabindex;
        $('[tabindex=' + tabindex + ']').focus().select();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```